# D7 Node Field: Create OG Member Checklist in Node Edit Form

Tags: entities, nodes, organic-groups

I'm using Drupal 7 to create an intranet site. I'm using OG groups to create committee and department pages. I want to create a field in a "Meeting Minute" node type where a list is populated with all group members. The node author could then select whether the committee member was present or absent at a meeting.

I'm able to use an Entity Reference field to select from *all* users on the site, but I want to limit these checkboxes to just group members.

I'm striking out here; any ideas on where to start would be much appreciated.

Using the OG 7.x-1.x branch.

**UPDATE:** I have tried to use the "Entity Reference View Widget" module to accomplish this, but that doesn't seem to work either.

I'm going to try to restate this for clarity — I need a field on a node edit page that allows me to select one or more users who are also members of a group from the organic groups module.

Answer (score 0):

Use hook_form_alter to do a entity field query or SQL query to get a list of UIDs that belong to 1 group ... OG may have a function to retrieve that list I dunno.

Once you have a list of UIDs use [Devel](http://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and `dpm($form);` the form object and you can simply `unset()` the `#options` values for UIDs that dont belong in the OG group. Here's a similar thing I did for limiting to a taxonomy term_reference field to a given level of a nested taxonomy.

If you're paranoid you can also append your own validator function to the form_submit function and cross check that valid UIDs (members in the OG group) are being saved .... but I dont usually bother to do that for intranet sites (I have "trusted" users / staff members ... not joe blow public).

Sample code doing basically the same thing for a taxonomy term reference field.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function eap_student_videos_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    switch ($form_id) {
      // Field specific overrides.
      case 'eap_studentvideos_node_form':
          $form['field_eap_video_country']['#after_build'][] = 'eap_country_term_limit_to_countries';
          break;
    }
}

function _eap_region_tids() {
  return array(24,35,48,8,4);
}


function eap_country_term_limit_to_countries(&$element) {
    $options = $element[LANGUAGE_NONE]['#options'];
    $result = db_query('
        SELECT tth.tid, ttd.name AS term_name
        FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy tth
        LEFT JOIN taxonomy_term_data ttd ON tth.tid = ttd.tid
        WHERE tth.parent IN  (:tids)
        ORDER BY 2 ASC
    ', array(':tids' => _eap_region_tids()));
    $country_tids = $result->fetchAllAssoc('tid');
    $country_tid_array = array_combine(array_keys($country_tids), array_keys($country_tids));
    $new_options = array_intersect_key($options, $country_tid_array);
    array_walk($new_options, function(&$value, &$key) { $value = str_replace('-','',$value); });
    // array_merge() destroys the array keys.
    $new_options = array('_none' => '- Select a value -') + $new_options;
    $element[LANGUAGE_NONE]['#options'] = $new_options;
    return $element;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try this today and let you know if it works for me.